# decode pandas columns (categorical data to metric data) by template (pivot table) with constraints

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, decoding, data-preprocessing

In `df` `A` and `B` are label encoded categories all belonging to a certain subset (`typ`).
This categories should now be encoded/decoded again ... into metric data  ... taken from template

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,2,2,2,3,3,2,3,1,1],
                   'B': [2,3,1,1,1,3,2,2,0,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,2,1],
                   'typ': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})
```

A and B should be decoded to metric(float) data from the templates pivot_A and pivot_B respectively. In the templates the headers are the values to replace, the indices are the conditions to match and the values are the new values:

```
pivot_A = pd.DataFrame(np.array([np.random.rand(9),np.random.rand(9),np.random.rand(9),np.random.rand(9)]).T,
                      columns=np.unique(df.A),
                      index = np.unique(df.typ))

pivot_B = pd.DataFrame(np.array([np.random.rand(9),np.random.rand(9),np.random.rand(9),np.random.rand(9)]).T,
                      columns=np.unique(df.B),
                      index = np.unique(df.typ))
```

pivot_B looks like:

```
In [5]: pivot_B
Out[5]: 
         0         1         2         3
type                                        
1     0.326687  0.851405  0.830255  0.721817
2     0.496182  0.769574  0.083379  0.491332
3     0.442760  0.786503  0.593361  0.470658
4     0.100724  0.455841  0.485407  0.211383
5     0.989424  0.852057  0.530137  0.385900
6     0.413897  0.915375  0.708038  0.846020
7     0.548033  0.670561  0.900648  0.742418
8     0.077552  0.310529  0.156794  0.076186
9     0.463480  0.377749  0.876133  0.518022
```

pivot_A looks like:

```
In [6] pivot_A
Out[6]: 
             0         1         2         3
type                                        
1     0.012808  0.128041  0.001279  0.320740
2     0.615976  0.736491  0.879216  0.842910
3     0.298637  0.828012  0.962703  0.736827
4     0.700053  0.115463  0.670091  0.638931
5     0.416262  0.633604  0.504292  0.983946
6     0.956872  0.129720  0.611625  0.682046
7     0.414579  0.062104  0.118168  0.265530
8     0.162742  0.952069  0.112400  0.837696
9     0.123151  0.061040  0.326437  0.380834
```

explained useage of pivots:

```
if df.typ == pivot.index and df.A == X:
df.A = pivot_A.loc[typ][X]
```

decoding could be done by:

```
for categorie in [i for i in df.columns if i != 'typ']:
    for col in np.unique(df[categorie]):
        for type_ in np.unique(df.typ):
            df.loc[((df['typ']==type_) & (df[categorie]==col)), categorie] = locals()['pivot_{}'.format(categorie)].loc[type_,col]
```

and result in:

```
In[7] :df
Out[7]: 
           A         B  typ
0   0.012808  0.830255    1
1   0.736491  0.491332    2
2   0.962703  0.786503    3
3   0.638931  0.455841    4
4   0.416262  0.852057    5
5   0.129720  0.846020    6
6   0.118168  0.900648    7
7   0.837696  0.156794    8
8   0.123151  0.463480    9
9   0.001279  0.830255    1
10  0.879216  0.083379    2
11  0.962703  0.593361    3
12  0.638931  0.211383    4
13  0.983946  0.385900    5
14  0.611625  0.846020    6
15  0.265530  0.742418    7
16  0.952069  0.156794    8
17  0.061040  0.377749    9
```

BUT this looping seems NOT to be the best way doing it, right?!
How can I improve the code? pd.replace or dictionaries seem to be reasonable... but I can not figuere how to handle it with the extra `typ` conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

melting down the 3xlooping process to one loop helps to reduce the duration time a lot:

```
old_values = list(pivot_A.columns) #from template
new_values_df = pd.DataFrame() #to save the decoded values without overwriting the oldvalues
for typ_ in pivot_A.index: #to match the condition (correct typ in every loop seperately)
    new_values = list(pivot_A].loc[cl])
    new_values_df = pd.concat([(df[df['typ']==typ]['A'].\
                                replace(old_values,new_values)).to_frame(A), new_values_df])
```